# Maxtor 6B250S0 from iMac mount on Windows 10 USB

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, sata, imac, sata-to-usb

I'm trying to plug a Maxtor disk drive pulled out of what I assume is a G5 iMac. I'm plugging it into an "Aukey" USB adapter caddy and trying to access on Windows 10.

I get a "Device not migrated" error in Device Manager:

[image: Maxtor showing in Device Manager]

The "Maxtor MaxBlast" recognises the disk but labels it as unallocated / no partitions:

[image: Maxtor MaxBlast application]

I've tried "HFSExplorer" to see whether it's a partition format (HFS+ ?) that Windows doesn't recognise. It doesn't auto-detect any matching partitions.

The disk doesn't sound too healthy in the caddy (a bit of high pitched noise and whirring on startup) but not as bad as some other working drives I've had before!

I'm just trying to read from the drive and pull a few photos off before reformatting; no need to write to the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the partition table on the drive is a legacy APT (Apple partition table), which neither Windows itself nor the modern day tools recognize.

The easiest way out is to boot into Linux (use a Ubuntu "Live" USB Stick it won't Install or otherwise ruin you Windows Installation), as most Distros natively support APT.

Comment: Worked well first time. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting permission problems for the files I'm trying to copy but I'm sure I can get elevated permissions on Ubuntu and sort that out (I'll just rtfm for a couple of minutes). There's no encryption so hopefully no problem.

Comment: Google says "sudo -i" (to run chown). Sounds reasonable.